# Why can't I import two Python files on the same level the same way?

Tags: python

I want to import `file1.py` and `file2.py`, which are both on the same level. I used the same code to import `file1.py` and `file2.py` but am still getting a modulenotfound error for `file2.py` while importing `file1.py` works fine.

The file structure is like this:

current_folder -> current_file -> import_folder -> file1.py, file2.py

I want to import `file1.py` and `file2.py` in `current_file`.

I imported sys and added:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(sys.path[0], '../'))
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:\\Users\\Bob\\current_folder\\import_folder')

import file1
import file2
```

However, I keep getting a modulenotfound error about `file2.py`.

Comment: What happens if you rename `file1.py` to `file3.py` and `file2.py` to `file4.py` and change the code from `import file1` to `import file3` and `import file2` to `import file4`?

Comment: `sys.path.insert(0, 'C:\\Users\\Bob\\current_folder\\import_folder')` doesn't contain `current_file` so is not a valid path and will be skipped.

Comment: you shouldn't be messing with `sys.path` at all, almost certainly

Comment: @mkrieger1 I found that when I created a new blank file5.py in the same folder and tried "import file5", I ran into the same modulenotfound problem as I did with the original file2.py. Is there perhaps something strange with my file1.py?

Comment: I don't know, but what happens when you try what I suggested before?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I get a modulenotfounderror for file3 (which has the same contents as file1.py, which used to work.)

Comment: I have the impression that you are trying to import code from a different location than you think and that it accidentally works for file1.py because you have a copy of it in the correct location.

Comment: Wait I actually just figured it out. It was in the right place actually; I just discovered that I could do from .import_folder import file1 and from .import_folder import file2 once I removed the sys.path.insert line and it works now. Thank you so much for all your help and support though!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to modify your path at all. When you execute `current_file`, `current_folder` will be added to your path automatically, which means you can refer to (the package) `import_folder` directly. (You may need to add `import_folder/__init__.py` to make it work.)

```
import import_folder.file1
import import_folder.file2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response @chepner! Unfortunately, when I try that, I get an error saying "no module named import_folder". I also did add a blank __ init __.py inside import_folder.

Comment: `init.py` or `__init__.py`?

Comment: The second one.

Comment: The claims made in this answer are somewhat environment-dependent (see [`-I`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-I) and [`-P`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-P) options). It also assumes `current_file` is being run as a script, which I don't see much evidence for in the question.